# Http Passthrough Pluggable Protocol for Firefox

Tags: http, firefox, protocols, pluggableprotocol

How can I make an http passthrough pluggable protocol for IE work in Firefox?

Alternatively, how to develop one for Firefox?  Any examples would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write an XPCOM object that implements nsIObserver. Then create listener for http-on-modify-request and http-on-examine-response.

```
var myObj = new MyObserver(); //implements nsIObserver
var observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
observerService.addObserver(myObj "http-on-modify-request",   false);
observerService.addObserver(myObj, "http-on-examine-response", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

On Firefox, if you would like to bypass a default behavior in a "pluggable" manner, you could write an [NPAPI based plugin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Plugins).  Let's say that the documentation is thin on this subject... but to get you started, you could consult [this](http://jldupont.blogspot.com/2009/11/notes-on-npapi-based-plugins.html).

With an NPAPI plugin, you have access to the whole OS and thus are free to expose any other resources to Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Write an XPCOM object that implements nsIProtocolHandler. For example, you can access local images from web pages:

```
const Cu = Components.utils;
const Ci = Components.interfaces;
const Cm = Components.manager;
const Cc = Components.classes;
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm");+
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm");
/***********************************************************
class definition
***********************************************************/
function sampleProtocol() {
     // If you only need to access your component from JavaScript, 
     //uncomment   the following line:
     this.wrappedJSObject = this;
}   
sampleProtocol.prototype = {
classDescription: "LocalFile sample protocol",
classID:          Components.ID("{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}"),
contractID:       "@mozilla.org/network/protocol;1?name=x-localfile",
QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI([Ci.nsIProtocolHandler]),
//interface nsIProtocolHandler
 allowPort :function(port, scheme)
 {
  if ((port == 80)&&(scheme == x-localfile)) {
   return true;
 }
 else
 {
     return false;
 }
},

newChannel: function(aURI)
{
    // Just example. Implementation must parse aURI
    var file = new FileUtils.File("D:\\temp\\getImage.jpg");
    var uri = NetUtil.ioService.newFileURI(file);
    var channel = NetUtil.ioService.newChannelFromURI(uri);
    return channel;
},
newURI(aSpec, aOriginCharset, aBaseURI)
{
    //URI looks like x-localfile://example.com/image1.jpg
    var uri = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/simple-uri;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIURI);
    uri.spec = aSpec;
    return uri;
},
scheme: "x-localfile",
defaultPort: 80,
protocolFlags: 76
};
var components = [sampleProtocol];
if ("generateNSGetFactory" in XPCOMUtils)
var NSGetFactory = XPCOMUtils.generateNSGetFactory(components);  //   Firefox 4.0 and higher
else
var NSGetModule = XPCOMUtils.generateNSGetModule(components);    // Firefox 3.x
```

**Be carefull! This approach can create vulnerability**